# Asyncio loop with several servers

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, nats.io

I have the following snippet of code that should run a websockets server + a NATS server.

Each time a new message gets to NATS, the websocket server should send the messages to all connected websockets. I see a strange behavior, as the websocket connections do not remain active.

I guess I have mixed things up in the asyncio loop. Any idea what I'm missing here ?

```
import asyncio
import os
import logging
import json
import websockets
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS

async def main():
    #
    # websocket related stuff
    #
    clients = set()

    # Register each new client
    async def register(websocket, path):
        clients.add(websocket)
    await websockets.serve(register, "localhost", 8765)

    # NATS related stuff
    # Send message to all connected websockets
    async def message_handler(msg):
        data = msg.data.decode()
        logging.debug('handling new message: {}'.format(data))
        for ws in clients:
            await ws.send("test")

    # Connection to NATS message queue
    nats_url = os.getenv('NATS_URL', 'nats://nats:4222')
    nc = NATS()
    await nc.connect([nats_url])

    # Subscription to all data related messages
    await nc.subscribe("data.*", cb=message_handler)

    await asyncio.Event().wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Each time a new websocket client connects, the connection closes after the registration:

```
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - state = CONNECTING
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - event = connection_made(<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=6 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>)
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - event = data_received(<535 bytes>)
DEBUG:websockets.server:server < GET /?token=234RZRZER HTTP/1.1
DEBUG:websockets.server:server < Headers([('Host', '127.0.0.1:8765'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Upgrade', 'websocket'), ('Origin', 'file://'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br'), ('Accept-Language', 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'), ('Sec-GPC', '1'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Key', 'KL0hFYOjOc25n/XwcON/9A=='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits')])
DEBUG:websockets.server:server > HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
DEBUG:websockets.server:server > Headers([('Upgrade', 'websocket'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', 'JpQAUwE+IzhPyNdqQuLeyROFhGo='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate'), ('Date', 'Wed, 04 Aug 2021 13:21:40 GMT'), ('Server', 'Python/3.8 websockets/9.1')])
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - state = OPEN
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - state = CLOSING
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server > Frame(fin=True, opcode=<Opcode.CLOSE: 8>, data=b'\x03\xe8', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - event = data_received(<8 bytes>)
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server < Frame(fin=True, opcode=<Opcode.CLOSE: 8>, data=b'\x03\xe8', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server x half-closing TCP connection
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - event = eof_received()
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - event = connection_lost(None)
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server - state = CLOSED
DEBUG:websockets.protocol:server x code = 1000, reason = [no reason]
```

Comment: I'd separate the two concerns (listening to NATS, handling websockets) into two tasks and maybe push messages between them using an asyncio.Queue()... that might bring clarity to the whole thing. The final infinite wait shouldn't be necessary either.

Comment: That said, what do you mean with "websocket connections do not remain active"?

Comment: @AKX sorry, I've added the connection / disconnection logs I get

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :) Your WS connection handler isn't an infinite async loop, so the connection is immediately closed by the websockets library.

Comment: hum... even if the whole main() is called in the loop ? I was pretty sure I did something bad in that setup :)

Comment: Yes – in the websockets library each client has their own coroutine. I'll write up an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want something like this – two tasks, one to serve websockets, the other to listen to messages, and a queue to bridge the two.

There may be some silly errors in this, since I don't have a NATS/websocket setup I could test things with.

```
import asyncio
import os
import logging
import websockets
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS


async def boot_server(
    stop_signal: asyncio.Event, message_queue: asyncio.Queue
):
    clients = set()

    async def register(websocket, path):
        # Register client
        clients.add(websocket)
        try:
            # Wait forever for messages
            async for message in websocket:
                print(websocket, message)
        finally:
            try:
                clients.remove(websocket)
            except Exception:
                pass

    async with websockets.serve(register, "localhost", 8765):
        while not stop_signal.is_set():
            # TODO: there's a small bug here in that the stop signal is only checked
            #       after a message has been processed
            msg = await message_queue.get()
            for client in clients:
                # TODO: should probably add error tolerance in this loop
                #       (i.e. if one send fails, others are still sent)
                await client.send(msg)


async def listen_nats(message_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    # Connection to NATS message queue
    nats_url = os.getenv("NATS_URL", "nats://nats:4222")
    nc = NATS()
    await nc.connect([nats_url])

    async def message_handler(msg):
        data = msg.data.decode()
        logging.debug("handling new message: {}".format(data))
        await message_queue.put(data)

    # Subscription to all data related messages
    await nc.subscribe("data.*", cb=message_handler)

    # TODO: figure out how to close the NATS connection?


async def main():
    stop_signal = asyncio.Event()
    message_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    ws_server_task = asyncio.create_task(
        boot_server(stop_signal, message_queue)
    )
    nats_task = asyncio.create_task(listen_nats(message_queue))

    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stop_signal.set()
    await ws_server_task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    asyncio.run(main())
```